# Cannot use Collection as Model PhalconPHP

Tags: mongodb, collections, phalcon, odm

I'm trying to setup MongoDB collection for my PhalconPHP application.

I have the mongo and collectionManager set up.

```
$di->set('collectionManager', function(){
    return new Phalcon\Mvc\Collection\Manager();
}, true);

//MongoDB Database
$di->set('mongo', function() {
    $mongo = new MongoClient("localhost:27017");
    return $mongo->selectDb("test");
}, true);
```

I have a model

```
class User extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Collection {
....
}
```

Then I got this error

> Unexpected value type: expected object implementing Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface, object of type MyApp\Models\User given

Comment: You may now delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Disclaimer: This was extracted from the question.</sub>

I was using Model validation instead Validation in the model body.